# PHP DOMDocument - why is en dash "–" converted to â€“

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, domdocument

I am using DOMDocument to extract some paragraphs.

Here is how my initial htm file that I am impotrting looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Toxins</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class=8reference><span>1.</span><span>Sivonen, K.; Jones, G. Cyanobacterial Toxins. In <i>Toxic Cyanobacteria in Water. A Guide to Their Public Health Consequences, Monitoring and Management</i>; Chorus, I., Bartram, J., Eds.; E. and F.N. Spon: London, UK, 1999; pp. 41–111.</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I am doing:

```
$dom_input = new \DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$dom_input->encoding = "UTF-8";
$dom_input->formatOutput = true;
$dom_input->loadHTMLFile($manuscript->getUploadRootDir().$manuscript->getFileName());

$paragraphs = $dom_input->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    if($paragraph->getAttribute('class') == "8reference") {
        var_dump($paragraph->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

The dash from "pp. 41–111" is converted to

```
pp. 41â€“111
```

Any idea why and how can I fix it in order to get utf8 unicode values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably because it's an m-dash or an n-dash rather than a simple ASCII hyphen character

Comment: Are you dumping to a console or a browser?  In either case, is the output channel configured to show utf8?  LANG= in console or Content-TYPE in browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the data is correct, you're just displaying it incorrectly.

Are you outputting in UTF-8?

The Ã + thing is a classic "showing UTF-8 encoded data as if it was other than UTF-8.

E.g.
If you're outputting to a web browser, try setting the character set with a meta tag.  E.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

If you need to output in something other than UTF-8 you'll need to convert into the alternative character set first.

Comment: Thank you, that resoolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When using PHP `fputcsv()` to generate CSV file. Use this before inserting data to `fputcsv()`

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'cp1252', 'utf-8');
fputcsv($file, $data);
```

This will surely stop conversion of dash to `â€"` when generating CSV.