# explode not works with dynamic string but works for static one

Tags: php, regex, xml

I have a xml. I won't post the xml structure completely. Just a piece of it.

```
<title>feeds IT â€”</title>
```

**When it doesn't work:**

I have this:  `$result = explode(" ", $xml->title);` This returns [`"feeds","IT","\u2014"]` which is wrong. The third one is wrong.

**When it works:**

```
$text = "feeds IT â€”";
$result = explode(" ", $text);
```

This works and returns `["feeds","IT","\u00e2\u20ac"]` which is correct. look at the third part. It's different from the above one and is correct.

But I need it to work dynamically and not putting that string by hand. It should work for `$xml->title`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using SimpleXML?

Comment: yes, i use simplexml_load_file to load the xml from web link.

Comment: Is your XML document UTF8 (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

Comment: yes, here i just copied the first line of the xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: I don't think SimpleXML works correctly for all characters. You might try: `$title = iconv("ISO-8859-15", "UTF-8", $xml->title);`

Comment: It worked, but with only one exception, instead of â€”, it returned â€  without (”). any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP DomDocument - why is en dash "–" converted to â€“](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959794/php-domdocument-why-is-en-dash-converted-to-%c3%a2%e2%82%ac)